# Belt is to thick for my snowblower, how to thin or leave?

Tags: automotive-engineering

So I got a new belt, and it was the right length but the wrong thickness. I needed a 3/8 belt but it was a 1/2. I did go to get it but the guy looked it up and told me I needed this one. So I got it. But when I installed, as I figured, there was a small issue.

So the belt is running up on the "brake" as I call it. It is along the idler and when not engaged this flat metal holds it in place, so the belt does not run when I do not want it to I guess. But the belt is so thick that it is rubbing against this metal when engaged, when the metal is far from the pulley (I think it is called). So it has been burning the belt from friction.

So this is my thought to solving...

1. Let it burn. I am sure it wouldn't take time to burn down to the right thickness. My only problem is that the 'strings' could show. If this is a good idea in general.
2. Cut that metal off. All I see it doing is keeping the belt from spinning when not engaged. But the belt would be loose were I do not think that would be a problem to begin with. So unless it does have another purpose than to just keep the belt from moving. Couldn't I just cut that off? Then it would not contact the belt and problem solved. Thing I do not like on this is when I do get the proper belt will it be needed then. Side thought: Does this keep the belt from falling off?

2nd Update: Another thought is, since the belt is too thick, how could I thin it while it is running? I would have to remove a whole 1/8 inch.

I do not want to return the belt, it was only $7 anyway. So I hope this was understandable and there is a answer to this.

Note: I again, am not sure were to ask a question like this so I wold hope this is fine.

Comment: Don't try to modify the belt. You'll damage its structural integrity.  Buy the correct size.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That will for sure be what I do next time :). When using it today, for our snowfall, there was zero burning, or friction. It worked great as long as the auger stayed engaged. Which is by my means just fine. Unless some animal/human finds it okay to see what happens....

Comment: Just to finish this 'thread'. After 2+ hrs of running there was nothing more than some of the belt worn off. It was not much but it turned out fine. Like Carl said, just get the right belt. But in my situation, it will work for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big item to note is a belt is not just a piece of rubber.  In fact, typical v-belts and other engineered belting systems have steel wires running through them:

[image]

These steel wires do all the real work, but the steel has a low coefficient of friction.  It would take a lot of area of wire allow the belt to operate with just the wire alone, without welding the wire in place.  The rubber has a high coefficient of friction, and allows the sheaves to grip the belt and let the steel do the work.

Bottom line is, don't modify a belt because you could damage the wires inside.  That's why they're sized differently instead of simply being modifiable.